# Checkboxes that are hidden on load don't post

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, codeigniter-2

i'm having a problem with submitting checkboxes that are hidden on page load.

I have a large form that I've split into several blocks. All of them are hidden on load and when the user selects a specific type of device I just show a block that contains inputs for that specific device type.

The problem occurs when submitting an input block that contains checkboxes. All other inputs (text, dropdowns...) submit fine, but checkboxes don't submit anything.

I removed the CSS class that hides the blocks and tried submitting then (so the whole form is visible on load), and checkboxes work in that case.

So... how do I actually get this to work? I know checkboxes as a HTML element don't post anything if they're not checked, but I didn't know about this "feature" if they're not present on load.

I'm using codeigniter btw, and just a regular POST - no ajax.

Comment: How do you "hide" those checkboxes?

Comment: Can you post what you tried/did so we have something to work with, or do you just want us to make up the code for you?

Comment: I'm not hiding checkboxes - I'm hiding a block of HTML code that contains input fields for that specific device type. Like I said - there are several.

Nothing is wrong with the HTML since everything works as long as the <div> that wraps the input fields is visible on page load (it has "display:none" and I use jquery to toggle it if that device type is selected)

Answer (score 0):

Dirty css trick:

```
.checkbox-test{
   clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
   /*Put it outside of the screen ?
   position: absolute;
   top: -9001;
   */
}
```

It simply creates a mask off 1 pixel, the checkbox is still accessible for the browser but to small to see